# Как узнать, выполнился INSERT или REPLACE?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

Здравствуйте, участники сообщества, я столкнулся с проблемой, что мне нужно выполнить sql запрос, примерно такой:  (python 3.5, sqlite)

```
cur = db.cursor()    

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE contact_info(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,"
    firstname VARCHAR(60), lastname VARCHAR(60), middlename VARCHAR(60),"
    "UNIQUE (firstname, lastname, middlename) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);")

cur.execute("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO contact_info VALUES"
            "((SELECT ID FROM contact_info WHERE firstname=? AND" 
            "lastname=? AND middlename=?), ?, ?, ?);",
            [fname, lname, mname, fname, lname, mname])
```

После чего мне нужно узнать, выполнился INSERT или REPLACE, но я не понимаю, как это можно сделать, не написав дополнительных запросов.
И мне бы хотелось понять, как правильнее всего можно это узнать?

Comment: А тот модуль `sql` не ругается при невозможности выполнить запрос? Обычно ведь исключение кидается...

Comment: не совсем правильный ответ, но все же.
можно просто поставить `flag` типа `boolean` и присваивать ему значение `True` при исполнении условия, а далее просто делать проверку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, [так](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html):

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Без дополнительных запросов не выйдет, к сожалению. В PostgreSQL, например, есть `RETURNING <id_name>`, который возвращает все модифицированные айдишники.